# CSS Rotate only the border

Tags: html, css, border, spinner

I want to make three circle spinners spinning around the text and the text inside these spinners will stay still.

I am only allowed to do this with CSS by referring to the `.spinner-border` in Bootstrap. The HTML file cannot be modified.

```css
.loader-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinner-border {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spinner-border {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loader {
  position: relative;
  left: auto;
  top: auto;
  width: 80px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  vertical-align: text-center;
  border: 0.25em solid currentColor;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
  animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader-wrapper">
  <div class="loader">Loading</div>
</div>
```

I have tried to make one spinner first. But I don't know how to make the text stay still.

Comment: make the border using pseudo element and apply the rotation there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.loader-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinner-border {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spinner-border {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loader {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: auto;
  width: 80px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  vertical-align: text-center;
  
}
.loader::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0.25em solid currentColor;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
  animation: spinner-border .75s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader-wrapper">
  <div class="loader">Loading</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very Nice~ Thank you!